# PHP, Printf,Sprintf Functions

Tags: php, printf

I am studying about printf,sprintf and i didnt understand few points, if can some one please help me understand thos points,

At This Link at [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

There are explanations are numbered from one to six:

What i didnt understand is: The First and The Second(1(sign specifier), 2(padding specifier)), if can some one please help me with example for thos i will be very thankful.

Comment: There are lots and lots of examples on that documentation page.  And you can always just try them out yourself!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sign specifier forces a  sign, even if it's positive. So, if you have

```
$x = 10;
$y = -10;
printf("%+d", $x);
printf("%+d", $y);
```

You'll get:

```
+10
-10
```

The padding specifier adds left padding so that the output always takes a set number of spaces, which allows you to align a stack of numbers, useful when generating reports with totals, etc.

```
 $x = 1;
 $y = 10;
 $z = 100;
 printf("%3d\n", $x);
 printf("%3d\n", $y);
 printf("%3d\n", $z);
```

You'll get:

```
   1
  10
 100
```

If you prefix the padding specifier with a zero, the strings will be zero padded instead of space padded:

```
 $x = 1;
 $y = 10;
 $z = 100;
 printf("%03d\n", $x);
 printf("%03d\n", $y);
 printf("%03d\n", $z);
```

Gives:

```
 001
 010
 100
```

Comment: Browser will not display padding if the padding parameter is blank space. Padding will be displayed only when some character is given as parameter

Comment: Of course. This is for textual output, not HTML. If you want HTML, use CSS for alignment. Or wrap in `PRE` tags.

Comment: This is right..sprintf() returns a string, printf() displays it.

Answer (score 30):

sprintf() returns a string, printf() displays it.

The following two are equal:

```
printf(currentDateTime());
print sprintf(currentDateTime());
```

Comment: That means printf prints as stander ed

Answer (score 2):

The sign specifier: Placing a plus sign ( + ) forces negative AND positive signs to be visible (only negative values are specified by default).

```
$n = 1;

$format = 'With sign %+d  without %d';
printf($format, $n, $n);
```

Prints:

> With sign +1 without 1

The padding specifier says what character will be used to pad the result to the specified length. The character is specified by prefixing it with a single quote ('). For example to pad to length 3 with the character 'a':

```
$n = 1;

$format = "Padded with 'a' %'a3d"; printf($format, $n, $n);
printf($format, $n, $n);
```

Prints:

> Padded with 'a' aa1

Answer (score 0):

**1.Sign specifier:**

By default browsers only display `-` sign in front of negative numbers. `+` sign in front of positive numbers are omitted. But it is possible to instruct the browser to display `+` sign in front of positive numbers by using sign specifier. For example:

```
$num1=10;
$num2=-10;
$output=sprintf("%d",$num1);
echo "$output<br>";
$output=sprintf("%d",$num2);
echo "$output";
```

Output:

```
10
-10
```

Here the `+` sign before the positive number is omitted. However, if we put a `+` sign after `%` character of `%d` then the omission no longer takes place.

```
$num1=10;
$num2=-10;
$output=sprintf("%+d",$num1);
echo "$output<br>";
$output=sprintf("%+d",$num2);
echo "$output";
```

Output:

```
+10
-10
```

**2.Padding specifier:**

The padding specifier adds certain number of characters to the left or right of the output. The characters may be empty spaces, zeroes or any other ASCII character.

For example,

```
$str="hello";
$output=sprintf("[%10s]",$str);
echo $output;
```

Source code output:

```
[     hello]             //Total length of 10 positions,first five being empty spaces and remaining five being "hello"
```

HTML output:

```
 [ hello]                 //HTML displays only one empty space and collapses the rest, you have to use the <pre>...</pre> tag in the code for HTML to preserve the empty spaces.
```

Putting a negative sign left justifies the output:

```
$output=["%-10s",$string];
echo $output;
```

Source code output:

```
[hello     ]
```

HTML output:

```
[hello ]
```

Putting `0` after `%` sign replaces empty spaces with zeroes.

```
$str="hello";
$output=sprintf("[%010s]",$str);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
[00000hello]
```

Left justification

```
$output=sprintf("[%-010s]",$str);
```

Output:

```
[hello00000]
```

Putting `'` followed by any ASCII character like `*` after `%` results in the display of that ASCII character instead of empty spaces

```
$str="hello";
$output=sprintf("[%'*10s]",$str);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
*****hello
```

Left justification:

```
$output=sprintf("[%-'*10s]",$str);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
hello*****
```