# PHP, Printf,Sprintf Function

Tags: php, function, printf

I am studying about `printf` and `sprintf` and I don't understand a few points. Can someone please help me understand the following `format` specifiers explained at [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

- An optional **alignment specifier** that says if the result should be left-justified or right-justified. The default is right-justified; a - character here will make it left-justified.
- An optional number, a **width specifier** that says how many characters (minimum) this conversion should result in.

Comment: Thank you Guys for your answers ill read them now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, Printf,Sprintf Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969371/php-printf-sprintf-functions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

width specifier:

```
given:    printf('|%5d|', 1);
prints:   |    1|
           ^^^^^-- 4 spaces + 1 char = width of 5
```

alignment:

```
given:    printf('|%-5d|', 1);
prints    |1    |
           ^^^^^-- 1 char + 4 right-justified spaces = width of 5.
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a simple example:

```
<?php

$strs = "hello world";
printf("%-15s", $strs);
echo "\n";
printf("%15s", $strs);

?>
```

**output:**

```
hello world    
    hello world

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|||||||||||||||
123456789012345  (width=15)
```

Here 15 is the minimum printed width of the string, and the `-` sign is to indent the string on the left.

Comment: Thank you ashwini, for your answer, have a nice day.